# join multiple table

Tags: sql, vb.net

i got 4 tables

table A

```
            code        accnt
           -------------------
            123          xxx
            222          yyy
            333          zzz
```

table B

```
           code         alloted
          -----------------------
           123            100
           222            200
           333            300
```

table  C

```
           code         ref      project
          -------------------------------
          333        11-2015     maintenance
```

table D

```
          code          ref      item       cost
         ---------------------------------------
          333       11-2015      hammer     100
          333       11-2015      nail       200
```

i want to join this table and have and output i like this

```
         code      accnt          ref     alloted
        -----------------------------------------
         123       xxx                        100
         222       yyy                        200
         333       zzz                        300
         333       maintenance    11-2015     
         333       hammer         11-2015     100
         333       nail           11-2015     200
```

i use left join for this but i can't get the field A.accnt, C.project & D.item to be combine as one column..thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to `JOIN` the first 2 tables and `UNION` in the other 2.

See if this works for you --

```
SELECT a.code, a.accnt, NULL AS ref, b.alloted
FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B ON a.code = b.code

UNION

SELECT c.code, c.project AS accnt, c.ref, NULL AS alloted

UNION 

SELECT d.code, d.item AS accnt, d.ref, d.cost as alloted
```

`UNION` will take distinct results when combining. If you want ALL results, then use `UNION ALL` instead.

Here is an explanation that might help you understand the difference between the 2 -- `JOIN` combines multiple tables by appending columns based on some criteria where `UNION` combines multiple tables by appending rows. There are MANY tutorials out there that explain `JOIN`/`UNION` if you need more information.

Comment: i'll try this one up..tnx sir :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the Solution:

select tableA.code, accnt, '' as ref, alloted from tableA join tableB on tableA.code = tableB.code 
Union ALL
select code, project as accnt, ref, ''as alloted from tableC
Union ALL
select code, item as accnt, ref, cost as alloted from tableD

Thanks!

Comment: i'll try this too..tnx sir :)